WIX How to let a script fail the installation
I am using WIX to create a Windows Instaler msi package. One of the files to be installed is a Powershell script that must be executed from the installer to register a scheduled task. When executing the script fails, the UI shows an error dialog, but the installer finishes as if nothing went wrong. But that is not what I want, I want the installer to fail on this and let it roll back all changes.
I have written a custom action (c#) to execute the Powershell script that runs after InstallFiles. But it seems that once InstallFiles has finished, there is no way of failing the installation. I did try to execute it before InstallFiles, but then I get the error that the Powershell script file is not found.
My question is: How can I run a Powershell script that is installed by the installer, and let the installer fail when executing the script fails?
Note that I use a Powershell script to create the scheduled task so that it is possible to recreate the task when the application has already been installed. So you do not need to run the installer again for that.

I solved the issue by making the Custom Action deferred. That way it runs between InstallInitialize and InstallFinalize and then failing a custom action fails the installation. My fear that files were not yet copied before InstallFinalize seemed unfounded, at least now that I am using a deferred action.
